# Total sum of increasing spend over a time period

Tags: summation, exponential-function

Let's say I'm spending $\$10$ a month on a service today, and the cost grows by $10\%$ a month. How much have I spent in a year?

I know that in $12$ months, I'll be spending $\$10\times 1.1^{12}$ per month, but I am not sure how to figure out the total spent along the way without adding all the individual monthly amounts as a large manual calculation.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Hint: [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@John Omielan has a perfect hint, try using a geometric series.

The linked resource in John's comment has the formula for a geometric series, which is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ar^{k}= a(\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r})$$
This represents the sum from time $0$ to time $n=12$ to represent twelve months in a year at a rate $r=1.10$ to represent the $10$% increase per month. $a$ is your $\$10$ per month.

Now, although it is not mentioned in your question, let us assume we are making a payment at the beginning of the month as you mentioned the service starts today, so the first payment is at time $0$ for $\$10$ and the $12$th and final payment is at time $11$ for $\$10*(1.10)^{11}$. This will be assuming $12$ total payments in the one year period.

Plug these values into your equation and you get
$$\$10(\frac{1-(1.10)^{12}}{1-(1.10)})$$

Try evaluating and this should give you your answer. I hope this helps and welcome to Math SE!

Comment: One thing the OP doesn't make clear, but you may wish to at least mention in your answer, is the issue of when the payments are made and exactly how many payments are made. Your result is basically assuming a payment is made at the start of each month, and includes the payment at the end of the year for the next month, for $13$ payments in total. However, if the intent is for payments at the start of each month for one year's worth, i.e., $12$ monthly payments, then $n = 11$ instead. Alternatively, for $12$ payments at the end of each month, it's also $n = 11$, but $a = 10(1.1) = 11$ instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan That's a great thing to mention, I'll edit my answer to reflect the situation.

Comment: Thanks very much! This is extremely helpful.